# SwiftUI project gets rejected by AppStore cause keeps getting empty white screen

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, appstore-approval

This is a SwiftUI + CoreData + CloudKit project that I'd been working on, the App works fine both on iPhone and iPad real devices for testing, however every time the App is submitted to the AppStore it get rejected with the same reason:

> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad running iOS 13.2.2 on Wi-Fi.
>
> Upon launch we notice that the app displayed a blank screen and no further action takes place.

Here is my Scene and App Delegates, there are no operations blocking the Main Thread but as i said before this version haven't been able to pass the AppStore Review process.

Any help is appreciated.

**AppDelegate**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import StoreKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
        
        DispatchQueue.global().async { ProductsStore.shared.initializeProducts() }
        
        return true
        
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {

        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
    }

    // MARK: - Core Data stack

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer = {

        let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "CoreData")
        
        // Enable remote notifications
       guard let description = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first else {
           fatalError("###\(#function): Failed to retrieve a persistent store description.")
       }
        
       description.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)
       
       container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
           if let error = error as NSError? {
               fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
           }
       })
           
        container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
       
       // Observe Core Data remote change notifications.
       NotificationCenter.default.addObserver( self, selector: #selector(self.processUpdate), name: .NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange, object: nil)
        
        return container
    }()
    
    
    @objc
    func processUpdate(notification:NSNotification){
        
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            
            let context = self.persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
            
            context.performAndWait {
                
                if context.hasChanges{
                    
                    do{
                        try context.save()
                    } catch {
                        let nserror = error as NSError
                        fatalError("Unsresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
        }
        
    }

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Scene Delegate**

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        
        let contentView = ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
       
        
        UITableViewCell.appearance().selectionStyle = .none

        // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
        
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
        
    }

    func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {


    }

    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {

    }

    func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {

    }

    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {

    }

    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.saveContext()
    }


}
```

Comment: What if there is no network connection?

Comment: Have you tried a TestFlight build?  Did you copy your development CloudKit configuration to production?

Comment: @matt If there is no network connection, the app works just fine

Comment: @Paulw11Actually the TestFlight reviewers sent the same issue but I was able to send a few videos of the app working and they did approve it regarding CloudKit, this issue is because an update, there is a version of the CloudKit in production already

Answer (score 0):

[SwiftUI iPad app shows black screen on enabling multiple window support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56843499/swiftui-ipad-app-shows-black-screen-on-enabling-multiple-window-support/56864529)

> ```swift
> let window = UIWindow(windowScene: scene as! UIWindowScene)
> ```

In `SceneDelegate.swift`, I changed

```swift
// Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
    self.window = window
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

to

```swift
// Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
let window = UIWindow(windowScene: scene as! UIWindowScene)
window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
self.window = window
window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```